# How to automatically format (indent) code written in any language

Tags: format, indentation, auto-indent

Many a times, all I need to do is to indent some weird code badly or not indented at all. If I want to make it readable, I need proper indentation. One way to do this is to paste it in Eclipse and use `ctrl`+`shift`+`F`. But it's overkill. And eclipse takes a while to open up.

Is there a lightweight tool to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the following site, it has options for how you want your code to be formatted:
http://prettyprinter.de/